# XKB Problem, cannot remap, Remapping unsucessful

Tags: keyboard, hard-drive, keyboard-layout, xkb

Hi I'm relatively new to ubuntu, but i don't know much about it.

My problem is that my keyboard has stopped working, not all of the keys But in particular the T and Y and the backspace buttons . I could use Onboard for it, but the problem is that I locked my hard drive and to access it i need to type in my password, which unfortunately comprises of a single 'y' then i heard about XKB, I was wondering if i could change the function of my tlde key to “y”, so that I can bypass the hard disk lock. I tried it to no avail. I was wondering if someone could help me through all the steps.
also, Do I have to install something?

Also, i should mention that I'm using ubuntu from a usb drive, i.e, the free trial of ubuntu. So i imagine the steps to do it would be different. The Ubuntu version 13.10

I can access my hard drive through the Free Trial.